# C++ reference return of class object- why not working?

Tags: c++

if i use the following code then why the ouput is same in following two cases:

```
class Test  
{  
    public:  
    int data;

    Test() { data = 9; }

    Test& myfunction ();
    void print() { cout << data<<endl; }
};  

Test m;
Test& Test::myfunction ()
{
    return m;
};    


int main()
{   
    Test b;
    Test a;
    b=a.myfunction();
    b.print();
    m.data=7;
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

in the above code why 'b.print()' outputs the same data on screen even after i hav changed the 'data' of 'm'...?
**'b' is a reference to 'm'. so if i change value of 'data' of 'm', value of 'data' of 'b' should also change automatically...**

output of above code is :
9
9// **why not 7?**

Comment: This is not a message board, so please avoid double-posting. Use comments and edits to change the original question instead.

Comment: As far as answering your question goes, `b=a.myfunction();` makes a copy of `m` returned by reference, so `b` is a separate object independent of `a`. Change to `Test &b(a.myfunction());` to get the effect that you want.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight has already been said in the first question, OP can not read apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get the same result if you would write

```
Test a;
Test &b = a.myfunction();
```

As for your code

```
Test b;
Test a;
b=a.myfunction();
```

then b is a separate object that was assigned a copy of m. So any changing of m does not influence on b. b was not defined as a reference.